# Kibana Pie Chart

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I build a REST-API and I added elasticsearch and kibana for better tracking. Currently, I try to show a pie chart and I will see a pie chart with the requested URLs from it.

I get a pie chart with all urls, but I like a chart count by the first part of my url. For Example:

```
3 requests to [GET]   /region/v1/address  
2 requests to [GET]   /region/v1/local-community  
4 requests to [POST]  /region/v1/local-community  
1 request  to [PATCH] /region/v1/city/09432  

4 requests to [POST] /authenticate/v1/login  
3 requests to [GET]  /authenticate/v1/check-access-token  
2 requests to [POST] /authenticate/v1/refress-access-token  

5 requests to [GET] /partner/v1/  
3 requests to [GET] /partner/v1/18113712
```

in the result, I like a pie-chart with

```
10 requests to /region
 9 requests to /authenticate
 8 requests to /partner
```

have anyone an idea of what I must do for this result? I'm new in eleasticsearch and kibana :D

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you can use a [Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html) aggregation:

[image]

I don't know which version are you using, in the example I used Lucene Query Syntax, but you can also use Kibana Query Language.

Notice that the more filters you create, the slower your visualization will be. So if you need many filters, I guess the best option would be to extrapolate that information before ingestion in Elasticsearch.

Comment: thx for the answer, can i use a regex for the filter? i dont like to add for each route key a specific filter. i dont feel corret :)

Comment: yes with Lucene -> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_regular_expressions